# How to compare SOM with K-Means?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I'm running an experiment relate to clustering, using two implementations:

a) self-organizing maps (SOM)
b) k-means

Are the results comparable? Are there metrics to compare results from SOM with K-means?

My question is not related to performance, but to the quality of results.

Answer (score 0):

You need a cost function. Usually, the cost function is related to application and data.

For example, if you have a ground-truth such as given two points, you know if they are in the same cluster or not. You can compute RAND index out of it.

Refer to [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) for many possible clustering metrics.